# Laravel Javascript - Check if theme exists in session, add class

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

I'm working on a system where the user can select a product and go to the next page. This product then gets saved in the session using laravel sessions. When the user decides to go to the next page and come back. The chosen product is indeed saved in the session, but the is no way for them to see what product they have chosen because the class isn't applied to the product that was chosen.

The code may clarify it better:

```
@foreach($themes as $theme)
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-4">
        <div class="card theme-card card-hover depth-2 border-0" id="theme-id-{{$theme->id}}">
            <a href="" class="theme-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#theme{{ $theme->id }}">
               <div class="card-image" style="height: 200px; background-image: url('/uploads/{{ $theme->thumbnail }}'); background-size: cover; background-position: center center;"></div>
               <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-2 vertical-center">
                            <i class="fab fa-magento fa-lg"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <p class="m-0">{!! str_limit($theme->name, $limit =  32, $end = '...') !!}</p>
                            <small class="text-muted">{{ $theme->productable_type }}</small>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
            <div class="card-footer bg-white border-0 text-right pt-0">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 text-left">
                        <input type="hidden" class="theme-name" name="theme[{{$theme->id}}]">
                        {{--<input type="hidden" value="{{ $theme->composer_package }}">--}}
                        <button data-card-id="{{$theme->id}}"  class="btn btn-orange btn-sm btn-theme-choice">Kiezen</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
                       <span style="font-size: 20px;" >€ {{ $theme->price }} EUR</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

In the above code, I for each trough every so-called "Theme" and I'm giving the ID of the theme as a data target and as ID. Then in my Javascript code, I do the following:

```
$('.btn-theme-choice').on('click', function (event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    newSelectedCardId = $(event.target).data('card-id');

    if(cardId === null) {
        cardId = newSelectedCardId;
    } else if (cardId !== newSelectedCardId) {
        $('#theme-id-' + cardId).removeClass('theme-chosen').find("input[name='theme["+cardId+"]']").val('');
        cardId = null;
    }

    var card = $('#theme-id-' + cardId );
    card.toggleClass('theme-chosen');
    selectedCardInput = card.find("input[name='theme["+cardId+"]']");

    if( !$('.theme-card').hasClass('theme-chosen') ) {
        selectedCardInput.val('');

    } else if ( $('.theme-card').hasClass('theme-chosen') ) {
        selectedCardInput.val('selected');
    }

    console.log(selectedCardInput);
});
```

Here I add the class to the card so the user can See which card they've selected. This choice then gets saved in the session using some PHP code in the controller

```
if( $theme == null ) {

    return redirect('plugins');

} elseif( $theme != null ) {

    foreach($this->predefinedArray as $value) {
        $request->session()->put('chosen_theme.' . $value, $theme->$value);
    }

    $request->session()->put('chosen_theme.composer_package', $theme->productable->composer_package);

    return redirect('plugins');
}
```

**problem**

How can I read the session and add the class to the card with the IDs that were stored in the session so if the person leaves the page and comes back, they can see what cards they've selected?

Thanks in advance

Comment: does the page reloads after a theme selection?

Comment: No, the chosen themes are put into the session after the user pressed the next button to go to the next page. because then the PHP code gets executed @ab_ab

Comment: $value = session()->get($key); also you can store variable in session by using shorter: session()->put($key, $value);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your view..

```
<div class="card theme-card card-hover depth-2 border-0 {{ \Session::get('chosen_theme.composer_package') == $theme->id ? 'theme-chosen' : '' }}" id="theme-id-{{$theme->id}}">
```

Whenever the theme id is in the session and the page loaded the class will be added, and if it is not in the session then the class won't be added.

Let me know the result..

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: My suggestion is not to misuse classes for this, what about using `data-attributes`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript

Comment: @ThomasMoors The op reloads the page after the session value is set, I just conditionally add the class to the the div based on the session value. How it would be misuse of class? Am not much familiar with the usage of data-attributes for this operation.

Comment: My bad, I thought you were adding all possible themes as classes. But you are not, so disregard my comment please :)